# Making the keyboard eject switch work

Tags: linux, keyboard, data-cd, eject

My keyboard switch for ejecting the CDROM does not work though it displays an eject button on the screen. I need to make it work. I know ejecting a cdrom using system call is as simple as

```
ioctl(cdromfd,CDROMEJECT,0)
```

But I don't know how to connect the an executable that contains the above system call and the event of pressing the eject key? Or shall I rely on kernel level? If then how?

Comment: It might try to call [`eject`](http://eject.sourceforge.net/manpage.html) -- have you installed that?  (Does `eject /dev/cdrom` in a terminal work?)

Comment: I don't have any problem with ejecting the cdrom using eject command. However eject key on my keyboard does not work.

Comment: I was just trying to find out what could be the reason for your eject key causing *the eject button display on screen* while failing to actually eject the cdrom... What's your desktop environment?  **The cdrom isn't mounted, right?**

Comment: I am using the default desktop environment of Ubuntu12.04.

Comment: So GNOME?  I'm not a user but a lot of DEs and window managers allow you to create custom shortcuts.  If there is a GUI interface to set them in, it will probably pick up the correct keycode for you, then you just link that to the `eject` command.

Comment: Yeah! It did work. I was wondering how the things where working internally :)